# How to read External Sqllite Database in xamirin android in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

My Code :

```
var dbpath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "ot.db3");
Context myContext = null;
try
{
      var dbcon = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
         var db=   dbcon.Query<records>("SELECT * FROM records WHERE sno = ? ", "1");
            int count = db.Count;
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    var reason = string.Format("The database failed to create - reason {0}", ex.Message);
    Toast.MakeText(myContext, reason, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

1. I Create a Sqlite Database from my SQL Server Database.
2. Now I save it to my Phone on this path (Android/Data/Application/File)
3. Now using Sqlite-net-pcl nugget package for Sqlite Connection the connection works fine showing have no error.
4. When I try to read a table from database this Give any error that "No Such Table exist in database". And the table exists in the database and is populated with data.
5. What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing the SQL query? You could make it more simple, something like, conn.Get(id);

You will only need to add [PrimaryKey] to your PK in the model.

Also, I suggest you to not use SQLite.SQLiteConnection and use SQLiteAsyncConnection instead, so you will be able to get data using "await conn.GetAsync(id)" and this way it won't block the main thread.

Comment: var dbcon = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);
List<records> li = new List<records>();
 dbcon.ExecuteAsync("Select * from records",li);  Still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Blank Database –** A database reference can be created by passing the file path the SQLiteConnection class constructor. You do not need to check if the file already exists – it will automatically be created if required, otherwise the existing database file will be opened.

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath);
```

**Save Data – Once you have created a SQLiteConnection object, database commands are executed by calling its methods, such as CreateTable and Insert like this:**

```
db.CreateTable<Stock> ();
db.Insert (newStock); // after creating the newStock object
```

Retrieve Data – To retrieve an object (or a list of objects) use the following syntax:

```
var stock = db.Get<Stock>(5); // primary key id of 5
var stockList = db.Table<Stock>();
```

For more info use following link:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/#Using_SQLite.NET

Comment: i have already sqlite database file. Here i want to retrive data from it. error:-> no such table: records

Comment: Try This

IEnumerable<records> recordsList  = (from i in dbcon.Table<Place>() select i).ToList();

Comment: it throw this exception : no such table: records

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your DB file if the table really exists.

Extract the database from your Android device/simulator with ADB
Example: adb pull //.db .

It will download the DB file to your computer.

Then, use a tool such as "DB Browser for SQLite" (http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to open your DB file and check if your table exists.

Other common mistakes when using SQLite with Android are:

- the file is not found (the path in your connectionstring is not good)
- the name is not the one your think (maybe in your case, it is "Record" and not "Records")

Hope it will help.